# My conclusion about the wrong theorem "Given a group $(G,\circ)$, prove that every nonempty subset $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup."

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, binary-operations

I came up with the following elementary theorem :

Given a group $(G,\circ)$, prove that every nonempty subset $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup.

- For every element, $a \in H$ from the definition of subset follows $a \in G$, and since $G$ is a group hence there exists $1_G \in G$ such that $a1_G=a=1_Ga$$\;$, and I think $1_G=1_H$ does not necessarily hold.
- For every $a \in H$ from the definition of subset follows $a \in G$,and since $G$ is a group hence there exists $a^{-1}\in G$ such that $aa^{-1}=1_G=a^{-1}a$.
- For every $a,b,c \in H$ from the same reason follows $a,b,c \in G$ and since $G$ is a group,hence $a \circ ( b \circ c )=(a \circ  b) \circ c $.
- For every $a,b \in H$ again from the same reason $a,b \in G$ ,and since $G$ is a group hence
  $a \circ  b \in G $.

---

From this work, I've concluded that **not necessarily** every subset $H$ of a group $G$  contains the inverse of the elements $\in H$, it's not true that $H$ does contain necessarily an identity element. In general, it's not true to say $H$ is closed under $\circ$, However, I think **it's true** to conclude that $\circ$ is necessarily associative for every nonempty subset $H$ of a group $(G,\circ)$.

I'm not sure how much of my conclusion is true, so it would be nice if someone confirms and explain the problems (if exists ).

Besides, it would be appreciated if someone gives me an example of a group that is closed under a binary operation, but there exists a subset of that group that is not closed under the same binary operation.

Comment: You should be able to come up with examples. Consider the set of integers, which is a group under the binary operation of addition. Can you find a subset of the integers that is not closed under addition?

Comment: "Prove that..." is not a mathematical assertion or a theorem.

Answer (score 2):

For *any* group $(G,\circ)$ with more than one element, if $g\in G\setminus\{1_G\}$ and if $H=\{g\}$, then $H$ is a nonempty subset of $G$ which is not a subgroup (since $g\circ g\ne g$).

But you are right when you say that, if $H$ is closed for the operation $\circ$, then $\circ$ is associative on $H$.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, it has to be closed for the operation $\circ$. Otherwise, there will be elements $a$ and $b$ of $H$ such that $a\circ b\notin H$ and so $\circ$ isn't even an operation on $H$. So, it makes no sense to ask whether or not it is associative (or if it has some other property).